# How to get all value of a particular data attribute on a page and use the collected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of elements with a data-attribute as follows:

```
<div class="first-div" data-month="march"></div>
<div class="first-div" data-month="june"></div>
```

Now I want to get all data-month attributes and add a click listener to it. The code now looks like this:

```
$('[data-month]').forEach(function(month) {
    $('[data-month="' + month + '"]').bind('click', function() {
        // Do something
    });
});
```

This however, does not work. The month element cannot seem to be used. Does anyone know how to make it work?

<sup>And does it work in all browsers?</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `month` variable is going to be a jquery object. You need to extract the string value for the month.

But from what I can tell, this doesn't seem necessary. You can just assign the event listener directly to the object inside the `each`

Try doing:

```
$('[data-month]').each(function(i, monthEl) {
    $(monthEl).bind('click', function() {
        // If you need to get the month value, you can use jQuery's .data()
        var monthString = $(monthEl).data('month');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a cleaner way to extract the month value? I am using it multiple times and find     `$('[data-month]').forEach(function(e) { var month = e.data('month');` (with the extra assignment) a bit long.

Comment: I have to ask why you are doing this anyway. In your `forEach`, you are already iterating over the elements. Why must you find the element again inside the loop?

Comment: I have to call a url which makes use of the value. The code does not work by the way. Still no click event. :-/ The forEach call does not work (control just hops over it).

Comment: Returns `TypeError: $(...).forEach is not a function`

Comment: Ah, indeed. Edited again

Comment: Thanks Brennan. Is this each method compatible with most browsers? And how about the data-attributes?

Comment: Code looks as follows now: http://jsfiddle.net/u2Lzgwyn/5/. Do you see a way to clean it up? :) Thanks for the help btw it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

you should change `.forEach` to `.each` and the month argument would be a `div` element not a string.

```
$('[data-month]').each(function(month) {
    $('[data-month="' + month.getAttribute('data-month') + '"]').bind('click', function() {
        alert(month);
    });
});
```